# Cron job does not run

Tags: shell, cron, cron-task

Following is the entry in the crontab:

```
MAILTO=abc@gmail.com
45 14 * * * /home/user/simple.sh
```

I've also done `chmod +x` on the `simple.sh` But the crontab does not run, it doesn't even send an email.

`pgrep cron` shows an Id. I also tried bouncing crond. But no luck!
Could someone please point out the mistake here

The simple.sh script is:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo hello
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the `shebang` in your `simple.sh`? Also, what does this shell script do? Does it work from the command line on a manual run?

Comment: @ansh0l : Yes, `#! /bin/bash`. It does an echo. Thats it. Just wanna get the cron running.

Comment: I think your cron is definitely runnning, the issue is within `simple.sh`. How do you use the `echo`, do you redirect the output to any other file? For starters, can you try `45 14 * * * /home/user/simple.sh >> /home/user/cron.log` and let me know if the appropriate contents are outputted to the cron.log file?

Comment: @ansh0l : Its a simple `echo hello`. I tried making the changes you mentioned, but the log file was not created.

Comment: Can you copy paste the shell script itself in the question?

Comment: I tried the cron on my machine, and it works perfectly fine. Can you try to run it every minute `* * * * * /home/user/simple.sh >> /home/user/cron.log`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This works, the cron writes hello to cron.log every minute. But I'm not getting a mail.

Comment: Since this is from your local machine, do you have postfix / mutt or any other similar program configured? Check my answer. Configuring those should be a separate question in itself IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are doing a `echo` within the cron job script, you need to capture its output somewhere.

Your `shebang` and file mode (using `chmod +x`) are all right, so those aren't the issue here and running without `/bin/sh` should work fine.

Try using the following to see the output in `cron.log` file (This runs every minute)

```
* * * * * /home/user/simple.sh >> /home/user/cron.log
```

Note that cron jobs run in separate subprocess shell, with reduced environment, so its output won't be visible on your terminal.

Regarding sending of email - you need to have some mail package (like `postman`, `mutt` etc) configured for the cron daemon to send out error mails.

Comment: thanks man I spent whole day figuring what is wrong with my cron and at the end I just needed to add /bin/sh in crontab

Answer (score 4):

Do not use relative paths, but absolute ones. Also, indicate the binary running the script, that is `/bin/sh` (or whatever coming from `which sh`):

```
45 14 * * * /bin/sh /path/to/script/simple.sh
```

Comment: It didn't help. I'm not even getting a mail, not sure why

Comment: Is your script alone working or just stops working when used in crontab? Note it will just run once a day, at 14.45.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there shouldn't be a space in line 1 of your .sh script:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Although I could see why it would still seem to work from when invoked in an interactive shell (**#** could merely comment out the rest of the line).

Still, I'd guess at worst it'd merely ignore that line and inherit cron's interpreter of **/bin/sh**